# Vectorized Operation in R causing problems with custom function

Tags: r

I'm writing out some functions for Inventory management. I've recently wanted to add a "photo url column" to my spreadsheet by using an API I've used successfully while initially building my inventory. My Spreadsheet header looks like the following:

```
SKU | NAME | OTHER STUFF
```

I have a `getProductInfo` function that returns a list of product info from an API I'm calling.

```
getProductInfo<- function(barcode) {
    #Input UPC
    #Output List of product info
    CallAPI(barcode)
    Process API return, remove garbage
    return(info)
}
```

I made a new function that takes my inventory csv as input, and attempts to add a new column with product photo url.

```
get_photo_url_from_product_info_output <- function(in_list){
  #Input GetProductInfo Output. Returns Photo URL, or nothing if
  #it doesn't exist
  if(in_list$DisplayStockPhotos == TRUE){
    return(in_list$StockPhotoURL)
  } else {
    return("")
  }
}

add_Photo_URL <- function(in_csv){
  #Input CSV data frame, appends photourl column
  #Requires SKU (UPC) assumes no photourl column

  out_csv <- mutate(in_csv, photo =
                  get_photo_url_from_product_info_output(
                    getProductInfo(SKU)
                    )
                )
}
  
  return (out_csv)
}

#Call it
new <- add_Photo_URL(old)
```

My thinking was that R would simply input the SKU of the from the row, and put it through the double function call "as is", and the vectorized DPLYR function `mutate` would just vectorize it. Unfortunately I was running into all sorts of problems I couldn't understand. Eventually I figured out that API call was crashing because the `SKU` field was all messed up as it was being passed in. I put in a breakpoint and found out that it wasn't just passing in the SKU, but instead an **entire list** (I think?) of SKUs. Every Row all at once. Something like this:

```
#Variable 'barcode' inside getProductInfo function contains:
 [1] 7.869368e+11 1.438175e+10 1.256983e+10 2.454357e+10 3.139814e+10 1.256983e+10 1.313260e+10 4.339643e+10 2.454328e+10
 [10] 1.313243e+10 6.839046e+11 2.454367e+10 2.454363e+10 2.454367e+10 2.454348e+10 8.418870e+11 2.519211e+10 2.454375e+10
 [19] 2.454381e+10 2.454381e+10 2.454383e+10 2.454384e+10 7.869368e+11 2.454370e+10 2.454390e+10 1.913290e+11 2.454397e+10
 [28] 2.454399e+10 2.519202e+10 2.519205e+10 7.742121e+11 8.839291e+11 8.539116e+10 2.519211e+10 2.519211e+10 2.519211e+10
```

Obviously my initial `getProductInfo` function can't handle that, so it'll crash.
How should I modify my code, whether it be in the input or API call to avoid this vectorized operation issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not totally elegant but it works.

I figured out I need to use lapply, which is usually not my strong suit. Initally I tried to nest them like so:

```
lapply(SKU, get_photo_url_from_product_info_output(getProductInfo())
```

But that didn't work. So I just came up with bright idea of making another function

```
get_photo_url_from_sku <- function(barcode){
  return(get_photo_url_from_product_info_output(getProductInfo(barcode)))
}
```

Call that in the lapply:

```
out_csv<- mutate(in_csv, photocolumn = lapply(SKU, get_photo_url_from_sku))
```

And it works great. My speed is only limited by my API calls.